Tmux config not work after run tmux kill-server
I have tmux config file at ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf with many UI and keymaps customizing. I don't know why it's not display the window name at the status bar. So I run "tmux kill-server". It got reset to default and display the window name. But now that config file is not affect at all. I don't know why, please help me.
I config it from this:
https://github.com/craftzdog/dotfiles-public/blob/master/.config/tmux/tmux.conf

Make sure you are using version 3.2a or above.
Also check out for other conf files for tmux.
By default tmux will search tmux.conf in the following order:

/etc/tmux.conf
$HOME/.tmux.conf
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/tmux/tmux.conf
$HOME/.config/tmux/tmux.conf

Make sure you don't have any other conf file in there. Then run:
tmux kill-server

and then:
tmux

New session should have your config changes.

Actually the reason is I have this line at the top of the config file: tmux set-option status off that I accidentaly at to the config file I just delete it and it work! Thank you!
